# JOIN - получает не все результаты

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

не получается получить все результаты, получаю только:

```
Array
(
  [id] => 2
  [description] => деревянный карандаш
  [name] => карандаш
)
```

а другие данные?

Структура таблиц:

nomenclature

```
-----------------
id    | name
-----------------
2     | карандаш
1     | стул
----------------
```

description

```
-----------------
id    | name
-----------------
2     | деревянный карандаш
1     | деревянный стул
----------------
```

код запроса:

```
$q = DB::QY($link, "SELECT * FROM description INNER JOIN nomenclature ON description.id = nomenclature.id");


while($row = $q->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Во-первых выполни запрос отдельно в БД и посмотри что возвращается.

Comment: бесполезно.. пробую так - `SELECT * FROM nomenclature INNER JOIN  description using(id)` - возвращает первый результат

Comment: А если LEFT JOIN?

Comment: И используйте * только для тестирование

Comment: РАБОТАЕТ! Спасибо!

Comment: почему? а если нужны все поля? все перечислять?

Comment: Да. Вот у вас сейчас например поля `name` есть и в одной таблице и в другой

Comment: @korytoff, изложите, пожалуйста, ваши предложения в виде нормального ответа.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я сначала то же так подумал, но тут мои варианты не являются ответом, предлагаю вообще вопрос закрыть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перенесено из комментариев:

А если `LEFT JOIN`?

```
SELECT m.id as `id`, m.name as `name`, d.name as `desc` FROM `nomenclature` as m LEFT JOIN `description` as d ON d.`id` = m.`id`");
```